# Django best practice for reusing javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, templates

I have two javascript codes required by external libraries (jQuery X-editable and FineUploader) where I require my context variables. Therefore I cannot use an external js for this codes.

This is what I'm currently doing on my templates:

**some_important_template.html**

```
{% include "includes/editable_fields.html" %}
{% include "includes/fine_upload_template.html" %}
```

**fine_upload_template.html**

```
<script type="text/template" id="qq-template">

    <div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader" qq-drop-area-text="Drop files here">
        <div class="qq-total-progress-bar-container-selector qq-total-progress-bar-container">
            <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-total-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar qq-total-progress-bar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="qq-upload-drop-area-selector qq-upload-drop-area" qq-hide-dropzone>
            <span class="qq-upload-drop-area-text-selector"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="qq-upload-button-selector btn btn-info">

            <div>Upload a file</div>
        </div>
        <span class="qq-drop-processing-selector qq-drop-processing">
            <span>Processing dropped files...</span>
            <span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner-selector qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span>
        </span>
        <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions removals">
            <li>
                <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector">
                    <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar"></div>
                </div>
                <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner"></span>
                <img class="qq-thumbnail-selector" qq-max-size="100" qq-server-scale>
                <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
                <span class="qq-edit-filename-icon-selector qq-edit-filename-icon" aria-label="Edit filename"></span>
                <input class="qq-edit-filename-selector qq-edit-filename" tabindex="0" type="text">
                <span class="qq-upload-size-selector qq-upload-size"></span>
                <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-cancel-selector btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-retry-selector btn btn-info">Retry</button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-delete">Delete</button>
                <span role="status" class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <dialog class="qq-alert-dialog-selector">
            <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
            <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Close</button>
            </div>
        </dialog>

        <dialog class="qq-confirm-dialog-selector">
            <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
            <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">No</button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Yes</button>
            </div>
        </dialog>

        <dialog class="qq-prompt-dialog-selector">
            <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
            <input type="text">
            <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector btn btn-info">Ok</button>
            </div>
        </dialog>
    </div>

</script>

<script>

    var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
        debug: true,
        element: document.getElementById('fine-uploader'),
        request: {
            endpoint: '{% url "registrations:ajax_upload" registration.pk %}',
            params: {
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
            }
        },
        deleteFile: {
            enabled: false,
            endpoint: '/uploads'
        },
        retry: {
           enableAuto: false
        }
    });

</script>
```

**editable_fields.html**

```
<script>

    //turn to inline mode
    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';

    {% if registration.emergency_contact %} 

    $('#contact_first_name').editable({
        name: 'first_name',
        pk: {{registration.emergency_contact.id}},
        url: '{% url "profiles:field_inline" %}',
        params: "{csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{csrf_token}}', model: 'User'}"
    });

    $('#contact_last_name').editable({
        name: 'last_name',
        pk: {{registration.emergency_contact.id}},
        url: '{% url "profiles:field_inline" %}',
        params: "{csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{csrf_token}}', model: 'User'}"
    });

    {% endif %} 

    {% for parent in registration.tutors.all %}

    $('#parent_first_name_{{ forloop.counter }}').editable({
        name: 'first_name',
        pk: {{parent.id}},
        url: '{% url "profiles:field_inline" %}',
        params: "{csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{csrf_token}}', model: 'User'}"
    });

    $('#parent_last_name_{{ forloop.counter }}').editable({
        name: 'last_name',
        pk: {{parent.id}},
        url: '{% url "profiles:field_inline" %}',
        params: "{csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{csrf_token}}', model: 'User'}"
    });

    {% for phone in parent.profile.phone_set.all %}

    $('#parent_phone_{{phone.type}}_{{forloop.parentloop.counter}}').editable({
        name: 'number',
        pk: {{phone.id}},
        url: '{% url "profiles:field_inline" %}',
        params: "{csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{csrf_token}}', model: 'Phone'}"
    });

    {% endfor %}

    {% endfor %}

    {% for phone in registration.emergency_contact.profile.phone_set.all %}

    $('#contact_phone_{{phone.type}}').editable({
        name: 'number',
        pk: {{phone.id}},
        url: '{% url "profiles:field_inline" %}',
        params: "{csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{csrf_token}}', model: 'Phone'}"
    });

    {% endfor %}

    {% with registration.costumer as costumer %}

    $('#email').editable({
        pk: {{costumer.id}},
        url: '{% url "profiles:field_inline" %}',
        params: "{csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{csrf_token}}', model: 'User'}"
    });

    $('#first_name').editable({
        pk: {{costumer.id}},
        url: '{% url "profiles:field_inline" %}',
        params: "{csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{csrf_token}}', model: 'User'}"
    });

    $('#last_name').editable({
        pk: {{costumer.id}},
        url: '{% url "profiles:field_inline" %}',
        params: "{csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{csrf_token}}', model: 'User'}"
    });

    $('#birth_date').editable({
        pk: {{costumer.profile.id}},
        url: '{% url "profiles:field_inline" %}',
        type: 'combodate',
        params: "{csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{csrf_token}}', model: 'Profile'}",
    });


    {% with costumer.profile.address as address %}

    $('#address1').editable({
        pk: {{address.id}},
        url: '{% url "profiles:field_inline" %}',
        title: 'Enter Address 1',
        params: "{csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{csrf_token}}', model: 'Address'}"
    });

    $('#address2').editable({
        pk: {{address.id}},
        url: '{% url "profiles:field_inline" %}',
        title: 'Enter Address 1',
        params: "{csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{csrf_token}}', model: 'Address'}"
    });

    $('#zip_code').editable({
        pk: {{address.id}},
        url: '{% url "profiles:field_inline" %}',
        title: 'Enter Zip Code',
        params: "{csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{csrf_token}}', model: 'Address'}"
    });

    $('#city').editable({
        pk: {{address.id}},
        url: '{% url "profiles:field_inline" %}',
        title: 'Enter City',
        params: "{csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{csrf_token}}', model: 'Address'}"
    });

    $('#estate').editable({
        pk: {{address.id}},
        url: '{% url "profiles:field_inline" %}',
        title: 'Enter State',
        params: "{csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{csrf_token}}', model: 'Address'}"
    });

    {% endwith %}

    {% endwith %}

</script>
```

This works but I'm not sure if it follows Django Best Practices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not a good idea to combine javascript and Django template code.

Instead, write a wrapper function around your javascript that takes all your template variables.  I.e. create a javascript file containing:

```
var wrapper = function (args) {
    //turn to inline mode
    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';

    if (args.registration_emergency_contact) {

        $('#contact_first_name').editable({
            name: 'first_name',
            pk: args.registration_emergency_contact_id,
            url: args.profiles_field_inline,
            params: "{csrfmiddlewaretoken:'" + args.csrf_token + "', model: 'User'}"
        });
     // ...
}
```

in your view, create the `args` as a json value:

```
def myview(...):
    args = {
         'registration_emergency_contact': bool(registration.emergency_contact),
         'registration_emergency_contact_id': registration.emergency_contact.id,
         'profiles_field_inline': reverse(...),
         // ...
    }
    return ... , Context({'args': json.dumps(args)})..
```

Then in your template file, include the javascript file through a script tag and call the function:

```
wrapper({{ args|safe }});
```

This way your javascript contains just javascript, and you can use all available javascript tools to lint/minifiy/transpile/etc., and serve it as a static resource.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. I knew there was an "elegant" way to do this ;)